# UITextField - UIView Resize Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

Am programmatically creating a UIView, setting the frame for the view, then adding a UITextField inside the view. I've been stuck on this one for a while, I'm trying to get the whole UIView to resize based on the amount of words in the text field if that makes sense?

Thanks,
Declan

Comment: so you want to resize your view based on the text size, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a given width, you can use sizeThatFits:

Here below is code I use for UITextViews. Similar code can be used for UITextFields.

Example:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[myTextView setAttributedText:myAttributedString];
CGSize size = [myTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, size.height);
myTextView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: So I see a down vote here. Is this solution wrong? If so, can the down-voter please correct this?

Comment: OK, made it clear that I am answering the question, but not using UITextField - same approach tho.